# Why do websites based in any country have their ip in the USA when using cloudflare?

Tags: api, networking, ip, cloudflare, low-latency

I was looking at the websites of some Korean Exchange's APIs. When I did a lookup of they're ip on maxmind it says that they're using cloudflare with coordinates in the USA.

However, I know these sites should be around korea because pinging them from korea gives 1-2ms response times. Also, it would make sense that a korean exchange would they're servers based in korea. So how does cloudflare work? Is my data really being routed to cloudflare USA before being routed back to the exchange and then to the US and then back to me? If so, how am i getting such fast response times?

The website Im looking at is api.bithumb.com
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Cloudflare uses "anycast" routing, which means that all of Cloudflare's 180+ locations around the world use the same IP address. When you send packets to that IP, the packets are routed to the *closest* Cloudflare location to you. Cloudflare has a location is Seoul, so when you access a Cloudflare IP address from Korea, that's the location you'll almost certainly go to.

Cloudflare (usually) acts as a proxy in front of the web site's real server. Your HTTP requests go to Cloudflare first, and then are forwarded to the "origin server" from there. Sometimes, responses are served directly from Cloudflare (e.g. from cache, or from a Cloudflare Worker) without talking to the origin at all. There is no way to determine the location of the origin server without talking to the owner—part of the reason people use Cloudflare is to shield their origin server from direct access.

Note that when you ping a Cloudflare IP, your ping packets only go to Cloudflare and back; they do not go to the site's origin server. So, the ping time doesn't tell you anything about where the origin server lives.